# Adding unique fb like button to dynamically loaded content

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, dynamic, facebook-like

I need to add a facebook like button to menu items from a php cp menu –

I’m thinking of pulling in the information from each menu div and having it fill in meta data before sending it to facebook

```
<div class="menu_content_cell">
<span class="menu_title"><?php echo $menuItem['item_name']?></span>
<?php if($menuItem['item_desc']) {?>                                                    <br />
<span class="menu_description"><?php echo $menuItem['item_desc']?></span><?php } ?>
</div>
```

to fill in

```
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
    <head>
    <title>Sample</title>
    <meta property="og:title" content="Site Name <?php echo $menuItem['item_name']?>"/>
    <meta property="og:type" content="food"/>

    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name"/>
    <meta property="og:description"
          content="<?php echo $menuItem['item_desc']?>"/>

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.sample.com/menu.php"/>
  </head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

is this possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

How would I do it? Maybe if I could get a unique id for each menu item - I'm sure this is possible but I'm struggling to piece the parts of the puzzle together

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook indexes objects by urls, different urls mean different objects in their graph.

For example, these pages will be considered different:

- http://www.sample.com/menu.php
- http://www.sample.com/menu.php?item=3
- http://www.sample.com/menu.php?category=43

And so, you should differentiate pages which you want users to like by their urls, and based on the dynamic part (either using query string or pretty urls) output different og tags on the server side.

Comment: I understand that part of the process, we have separate pages like /sub-menu?menu=8709 etc, what I'm trying to do is target specific menu items from inside those pages, and have facebook see them - so a user could like the restaurants chicken tikka masala etc

Comment: sorry, just read that again, that makes sense - I'll give it a go

Answer (score 0):

use fb open graph meta tag og:type and set it as "article" for your dynamic page html header

```
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
```

other fb opengraph meta tags

```
<meta property="og:title" content="your dynamic title">
<meta property="og:image" content="your dynamic image url">
<meta property="og:url" content="your dynamic page url">
<meta property="og:description" content="your dynamic content">
```